# Display file size with find command prior to the paths

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to find a way to combine the results that are displayed with the `find` command, e.g:

```
$find /home -name "requirements_*"

/home/cobayo/Obligatorio Test 2/requirements_richard
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio Test 2/requirements_paul
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio Test 2/requirements_george
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio Test 1/Subdirectorio/requirements_joe
```

So here I get all of the paths of the files I am looking for, what I would like to do is to get the file size listed prior the paths. 
For instance:

```
34K "/home/cobayo/Obligatorio Test 2/requirements_richard"
```

I have some commands, even a little script does show me file sizes.

For example, this one:

```
find /home -name "requirements_*" -mtime -1 -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc |
    tail -n1*
```

And it shows the TOTAL size of all files with the name given as a parameter as results.

But then, I also have this little script:

```
FILENAME=$1                                   
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
echo "Size of $FILENAME = $FILESIZE bytes."
```

Which is perfect as I get the file in K of the specific file. I tried to mix them up using a list:

```
*for i in `find /home -name "requirements_*"`
do
echo `stat -c%s $i`
done*
```

But I don't get the results Im looking for, in fact it tells me the files don't exist :(

Comment: What if you surround $i in quotes? Like this "$i". You have spaces in full path returned by find

Comment: search here for `[linux] find xargs` (don't use the `for` loop, but do use your little script). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-exec du -hs {} \;`:

```
$ find -type f -exec du -hs {} \;
4.0K    ./proj-2/README.md
4.0K    ./proj-2/file.c
4.0K    ./proj-2/file.h
```

or alternatively, if your `find` supports it:

```
find -type f -exec du -hs {} +
```

which calls `du` just once.

Or `-printf` with the `%k` formatting parameter for the size in kB:

```
$ find -type f -printf '%kK\t%p\n'
4K      ./proj-2/README.md
4K      ./proj-2/file.c
4K      ./proj-2/file.h
```

Manual references:

- [`-exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Single-File), single file
- [`-exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files), multiple files
- [`-printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dprintf-70)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Benjamin! In my understanding, the du command will give you the size in **blocks** of your file but not the actual file size.

Comment: @Allan The `-h` option prints the normal units, I'd say.

Comment: the `-h` option is human readable, so indeed it will be in K,M,G however the size will be counted in blocks, for big files it does not matter a lot but for small files it does! :-)

Comment: @Allan Can you give an example of where `du -h` does not show the actual disk usage? A tiny file occupies 4 kB. My Ubuntu uses 512 byte blocks, yet `du -h` reports 4.0K for the file. Looks right to me, as in "kilobyte", and no blocks at all. My `du` (GNU Coreutils 8.25) defaults to block sizes of 1 kB if nothing else is specified, so I don't think the solution I'm proposing shows anything other than the actual disk usage of the files.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script/185039

More especially:  
*"du doesn't give the size of the file, it gives an indication of how much space the file uses, which is subtly different (usually the size reported by du is the size of the file rounded up to the nearest number of blocks, where a block is typically 512B or 1kB or 4kB)"*

Comment: @Allan That's why I wrote "disk usage". I assumed the OP wanted to use `du` because that's what he had in his attempt. `-printf` does the same, it displays disk space used. I agree that if you want the actual size, you need `stat` (like you did) or something like `wc -c`, which would be quite a bit slower than `du` or `printf '%k`, I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not put the variable `$i` between `double quotes` the spaces will be interpreted as separator and your command will try to asses the following files independently :

```
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio 
Test 
1/Subdirectorio/requirements_joe
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio 
Test 
2/requirements_richard
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio 
Test 
2/requirements_paul
/home/cobayo/Obligatorio 
Test 
2/requirements_george
```

what gives you the error: *files don't exist*

You can try:

```
find . -name "requirements_*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c "echo -n 'Size of {} = '  && stat -c%s '{}' | tr -d '\n' && echo ' bytes.'"
```

[image]